# EntityState=Deleted. entry.GetDatabaseValues() returns null

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on EF4.0. My grid is bound to an entity.
When I add a new row to the grid, context tracks it and when I click save changes these are saved to DB.

Today the user tried to add a new row and delete the same row. All this before clicking the save button. So as per my understanding, since the user added a new row first, entitystate should be set to added. Then the user deleting the same row, entity state should be set to deleted.

So there should be two changes made to the context. But thats not what is happening.Context only shows one operation. Entitystate=deleted entry.GetDatabaseValues() returns null

If I do the same to two different rows(add a new row and delete an already existing- saved row), it behaves correctly.

```
    public AuditClass GetAudit(DbEntityEntry entry)
        {
            AuditClass audit = new AuditClass();
            audit.EntityName = GetTableName(entry);
            audit.EntityId = GetKeyValue(entry);

            //entry is Added 
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                audit.AuditProperties = SetAddedProperties(entry);
                audit.Action = AuditActions.I.ToString();
            }
            //entry in deleted
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                audit.AuditProperties = SetDeletedProperties(entry);
                audit.Action = AuditActions.D.ToString();
            }
            //entry is modified
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                audit.AuditProperties = SetModifiedProperties(entry);
                audit.Action = AuditActions.U.ToString();
            }


  private ObservableListSource<AuditProperty> SetDeletedProperties(DbEntityEntry entry)
        {
            ObservableListSource<AuditProperty> detailList = new ObservableListSource<AuditProperty>();
            DbPropertyValues dbValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                foreach (var propertyName in dbValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    var oldVal = dbValues[propertyName];
                    if (oldVal != null)
                    {
                        detailList.Add(new AuditProperty
                        {
                            PropertyName = propertyName,
                            OldValue = oldVal.ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }

            return detailList;
        }
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delete *replaces* the added entitystate, this is why only the deleted row comes back.

GetDatabaseValues() does as it says on the tin - gets values from the database. As the entity has never saved to the database the values of course will be null.